# Better performance and readability for a C# tree

Tags: c#, tree, binary-tree

I want to create a tree in C#, this tree will be binary, so it will have the current node and 2 more nodes, NodeYes and NodeNot.

Which of the two representations is better in terms of readability and performance?

```
 public class Tree_1
    {
        public No NodeActual { get; set; }
        public No NodeYes { get; set; }
        public No NodeNot { get; set; }
    }


    public class Tree_2
    {
        public No NodeActual { get; set; }
        List<No> NodeChidrens { get; set; }
        // position 1 - no
        // position 1 - yes
    }
```

Comment: Imo the first one

Comment: hello b0neng4, why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. All you need is

```
public class TreeNode 
{ 
    public TreeNode Left; 
    public TreeNode Right; 
    public object NodeData; 
    public void SomeMethod() 
    { 
         DoSomething(Left); 
         DoSomething(Right);
         DoSomething(this); // if you want to reference the current node
         // Left.NodeData, Right.NodeData and this.NodeData or simply NodeData 
    }
}
```

To keep track of the tree just keep the root node

```
public class Tree
{
    public TreeNode Root;
}
```

The `List<>` idea is great if generalising to n-ary trees (up to n child nodes) but there's no point for binary trees and probably a (negligible) performance penalty to go with the extra indexing complexity.

Look into recursion - very powerful, intuitive way to traverse trees - with some hazards (one of which is religion that preaches against it;-)  My advice: learn it, understand its limitations and by the time it has become your friend you will also know when to put effort into not using it.